# Issue in HTML special symbol while download, android

Tags: java, android, html

I am trying to download html content from one webpage to sdcard .Page contain special symbol as well.so i was think about UTF-8 to apply in HTTP request. but as i am download it, its not show in properly. special symbol which on webpage are convert in other character set. even I have tried so far to check with convert in different different Unicode character but its not solve my problem.
Here is snap for original webpage image.
[image]

Now after download this view source at android side and when i open file it show like 
[image]

So this is the issue now let i show my code snippet :

**Here You can see hit the webpage and get viewsource as in string**

```
   URL url = new URL(sWebUrl);
                URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
                responseString = IOUtils.toString(in,HTTP.UTF_8);
```

**Code for write html file**

```
try
    {


        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File yourFile = new File(dir, "Cherrypc/" + sWebsiteName + "/mysdfile" + iIndex + ".html");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(yourFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut,HTTP.UTF_8);
        myOutWriter.write(result);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

so please help me out this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the original page is in Windows Latin-1 as is my guess, you should load it in that encoding.
Java then intern in its String holds the Unicode version.

The encoding is primarily determined by the HTTP header like

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8869-1
Content-Encoding: ISO-8869-1

<html>....
```

This (optional) encoding can be determined and used:

```
URL url = new URL(sWebUrl);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
if (encoding == null) {
    encoding = "ISO-8859-1"; // HTTP default encoding: Latin-1.
}
if (encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("ISO-8859-1")) {
    encoding = "Windows-1252";
    // Browsers interprete Latin-1 as Windows Latin-1.
}

InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
responseString = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
```

In the HTML source text the encoding is specified too, and should be altered to UTF-8.

```
// Old HTML: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
String result2 =
    result.replaceFirst("([\"'])text/html.*\\1",
                        "$1text/html; charset=UTF-8$1");

if (result2 == result) { // Not replaced.
    // HTML 5: <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    result2 =
        result.replaceFirst("(?si)<meta\\s*charset=([\"']).*\\1>",
                            "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
}

if (result2 == result) { // Not replaced.
    // No statement, add one, to read as file:
    result2 =
        result.replaceFirst("(?si)<head>",
            "$0<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />");
}

result = result2;
```